# Launchd and cron can't send emails from automated python scripts and fail with: smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: please run connect() first

Tags: python, macos, cron, smtplib, launchd

I want to set up automatic backups for my website and created a working python script for that. For scheduling first I tried `launchd` and then `cron` and for both of them I got the same result, which is the backup works, but the email notification fails.

The script is 100% working as intended when launched from `Terminal` or `Sublime Text 3` and I'm using macOS Catalina Version 10.15.7.

The error log for both `launchd` and `cron` is this:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fast_email/fast_email.py", line 95, in send
    server.ehlo()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 440, in ehlo
    self.putcmd(self.ehlo_msg, name or self.local_hostname)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 367, in putcmd
    self.send(str)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 359, in send
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected('please run connect() first')
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: please run connect() first
```

The part of my fast_email package where the error happens (the `server.ehlo()` line):

```py
def send(msg_data, d):
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(d['EMAIL_SERVER'], d['EMAIL_PORT'])
    server.ehlo()
    server.login(d['EMAIL_SENDER'], d['EMAIL_PASSWORD'])

    message = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
    message["From"] = d['EMAIL_SENDER']
```

If that may be relevant, I'm using threads (`threading.Thread`) in my fast_email package, because sometimes I want to send emails fast to people in my company.

The problem is very frustrating and I've spent a full day on it alone, not to mention the other problems with launchd... Please, if you have any hints, I will be very thankful.

P.S. my cron job line is:

```
0 9 * * * (/usr/local/bin/python3 my/script/pathname.py > /Users/my_username/Desktop/cronjob.log 2>&1)
```

and I have

```
<key>AbandonProcessGroup</key>
<true/>
```

in my launchd .plist file.

Comment: Some servers require you to `ehlo` a second time after authenticating.

Comment: The parentheses in the `cron` job add no value, and cost you a process.

Comment: @tripleee If that would be a server thing it would also crash when ran from the Terminal. And it crashes on the first ehlo, so the second wouldn't have the chance to help. Thx for the parentheses tip though, I just used what I saw in some tutorial. Why using parentheses would cost me a process though?

Comment: That's what parentheses do; run the commands in a separate subshell.